# Is there a relationship between loop(topology) and loop(abstract algebra)

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, loop-spaces

It seems interesting that the term "loop" is used in both topology and abstract algebra.  Is that just a coincidence, or is there a connection between them?

Everything I have seen in my research associates the topological idea of loop more to groups than abstract algebra loops.

Answer (score 1):

The choice of word is probably just a coincidence. I haven't heard of any deep connection, nor can I spot one.

That is not to say that you can put a (algebra)loop structure on a set of (topology)loops. As you say, there are a few natural choices of operations between (topology)loops but those most often result in full-fledged groups.

Naming collisions like this happen all the time, of course. Consider "domain" and "regular" etc.

Comment: Also "kernel", "field", "normal"...